# How to I delete a previous SavedInstanceState?

Tags: android, instance

I'm making an Android app but I keep running into a odd bug. After the game, if you tap the 'Back' button on your phone, you end up back at the finished game and you can keep playing!!

How do I prevent this from happening? Is there a way to delete the previous `SavedInstanceState`? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want to restore the data don't pass them to your super class. However I would prefer to reset the game data myself.

I guess the full solution is to call `finish();`. I guess you have this activity stack: Menu -> Game -> End summary. So when you start your "game over" activity add a finish() call to close your current game. So a back button press let the user go back to your menu.